# Pagination when data source is supporting multi page requesting

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

Does Google Data Studio Community connector support pagination?

I work with an external data service. The service returns data page by page. It requires `start` and `next` parameters and it requires 2 req/sec. Can I override a method like `getData` or upgrade `request` argument for implement this feature?

If it's not. Is there the best practice for getting data of this kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community Connectors do not support pagination for web APIs at present.

The best practice would depend on your use case. If you want to get the full dataset for user, you can make multiple `UrlFetch` calls to get the full dataset, merge it, and return the merged set as the `getdata()` response. It might also make sense to cache this result to avoid making a large number of requests in the short term. You can cache using [Apps Script cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/), or a [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/), or even to [BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery). Keep in mind that Apps Script has [6 min / execution limit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations).

However, if you want to return only specific pages, the only way to configure that would be through `getConfig` since `configparams` are passed with the `getData()` request. Example use case would be returning only first n number of pages where n selected by user in the config.