# Google Data Studio pagination in custom connector getData: undocumented

Tags: google-apps-script, pagination, looker-studio

In the [getData()](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getdata) function I'm sometimes seeing some calls with a request that contains

`pagination={startRow=1.0, rowCount=100.0}`

and they seem to be ones that also have

`scriptParams={sampleExtraction=true}`

However, I can't see any documentation on `pagination`. Is this a stable feature? Will there ever be a request for a startRow that isn't `1.0`?

I'm asking since to make robust pagination for some of our data sources may not be trivial, so would like to know if it's worth the effort.

Comment: The `sampleExtraction` is explained in [Semantic Extraction](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/semantics#semantic-type-detection) but I've never got it in my connector. The ´pagination´ occured only once and I wasn't able to invoke it manually. But the meaning is clear. Use it if your API supports something like `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` (Limit x Page) as you will find in SQL statements as explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp). Ignore it if you API does not support pagination. It's an option to reduce the data transferred and increase the speed.

Comment: `sampleExtraction` is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/semantics#semantic-type-detection). It is only invoked if your schema (data fields) do not define any semantic type. It is recommended to define the semantics manually.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47169597/603541), made by [Minhaz Kazi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4024072/minhaz-kazi) (Google's Data Studio developer), Community Connectors do not support pagination for web APIs at present.

I also tried to implement pagination and it doesn't work.  Indeed, there are some weird requests made by Data Studio that makes you think you can do more than it is documented.